# Overlapping LinearLayout on map inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a google map and a linearlayout inside a relativelayout. The linearlayout becomes visible after certain interactions with the map and overlaps the map then.

The overlapping linearlayout includes some controls, but clicking or touching the controls in the linearlayout influences the map, which is placed below the linearlayout in the UI.

How can I make my linearlayout respond to touchevents (not the map)?

Here is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/general_map_fragment" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="200dp" >

        ...

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/general_map_fragment" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="200dp" >

        ...

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the clickable property on the `LinearLayout` to true. The `LinearLayout` will catch the event and will not pass the event to the map fragment.

Add this line in your `LinearLayout`

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Comment: I tried this before. But the result was that the map below was completely frozen and since the linearlayout overlaps only a part of the map, it sould still be accessible

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        layout="@layout/general_map_fragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="200dp" >

            ...

        </TableLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```